# How to validate an api response against a swagger schema using node?

Tags: node.js, swagger

I have API tests already.  I want to add to these some schema validation against the swagger schemas.  Are there any node libraries that can help me do this?

Comment: I'm using Request to make my api calls, so ideally a library that could be used with that...